# Token balance shows 0 in rinkeby etherscan

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I wrote a erc20 token contract and I deployed in rinkeby tetstnet. I given the toatl supply=1000000 but my token balance is showing 0 in metamask. How can I get the tokens and tell me the way to get the tokens. Below is my contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract COCOTOKEN {
string public constant symbol = "COCO";
  string public constant name = "COCOTOKEN";
  uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
  uint256 totalSupply = 1000000;
  address public owner;
  mapping(address => uint256) balances;
  mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
  modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
constructor() public{
  owner = msg.sender;
  balances[owner] = totalSupply;
}
function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
}
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) public returns (bool success) {
    if (balances[msg.sender] >= _amount
        && _amount > 0
        && balances[_to] + _amount > balances[_to]) {
        balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
        balances[_to] += _amount;
       emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _amount);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
function transferFrom(
    address _from,
    address _to,
    uint256 _amount
) public returns (bool success) {
    if (balances[_from] >= _amount
        && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _amount
        && _amount > 0
        && balances[_to] + _amount > balances[_to]) {
        balances[_from] -= _amount;
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _amount;
        balances[_to] += _amount;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _amount);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _amount) public returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _amount;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _amount);
    return true;
}
function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
}
}
```

and the the deployed contract address is "0xc3384a37d041b99d437734a80e88b39e0efa630d".Why token balance is showing 0.In rinkeby etehrscan it showing liks following 
    On-chain Token Attributes Check Result: 
     Total Supply = 0
     Name = COCOTOKEN
     Symbol = COCO
     Decimals = 18
     ERC-165 Interface = {Not Available}
     Implements ERC-721 = {Not Available}.
    Can any one please tell me how to add tokens?

Answer (score 0):

Because that is very small unit of your ether. just transfer for ether from faucet.
or just transfer in wei unit 1000000000000000000 then you will be see 1 ether on your screen.

Comment: I have to add this "1000000000000000000" in my contract code "uint256 totalSupply = 1000000;" here or

Comment: Just Transfer more ether from faucet then check that is reflecting or not . And one more things when you are doing transfer then you are getting transaction id. from transaction id  you can check transaction have been success or failed.

Comment: I deployed my contract using metamask. In metamask account already have ether.Now I want to send more ethers for  contract address or metamask address.

Comment: Ok , Just verify which contract you have deployed that is on right network or not. And please trying contract deployment from GUI ether wallet. their you can select your network where you want to deploy your contract. hope that will support you for track right reason for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase your `totalSupply` of with 18 digits of the decimal. for more explanation on `decimal` and `totalSupply` check this [Answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29082/smart-contract-token-creation-how-to-set-total-supply).

Comment: I increased the total supply like "uint256 public totalSupply = 1000000000000000000;" and deployed with metamask account but the tokens are not reflecting. I did any mistakes or can u explain the steps after click on the deploy button in remix

Answer (score 0):

The value that you assegned at the totalSupply is too low,you can check the erc20 token standard [here](http://%20https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard). In the constructor they set the totalSupply like in the code below:

```
constructor() public {
        symbol = "FIXED";
        name = "Example Fixed Supply Token";
        decimals = 18;
        _totalSupply = 1000000 * 10**uint(decimals);
        balances[owner] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), owner, _totalSupply);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The total supply you are giving is like totalsupply = 1000000 * 10^-18 which would come to 0.0000000000001 so obviously it will show as zero when you try to perform any transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete implementation using OpenZeppelin which sets total supply to 1000000 and assigns the tokens to you at contract initialization.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.2;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract TokenMock is ERC20
{
    constructor () public {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000);
    }
}
```